# Does transconductance (Gm) have 3dB bandwidth

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, active-filter

The voltage gain of an amp is Gm*Zout,
the bandwidth of the voltage gain is limited by the Zout as signal freq increases.
I wonder whether the Gm also has 3dB bandwidth or not.
And If Gm has 3dB bandwidth,what element cause it?

Comment: @horta change of amplitude over frequency is often expressed by a figure called [3 dB bandwidth](https://en.m.wikipedia.o/wiki/Half_power_point). Might not apply to Gm but it's a pretty standard concept for other filters, amplifiers, resonators, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the gm term may also have a frequency dependence which causes it to reduce (or increase in some cases) with increasing frequency. Therefore, the overall gain reduces because of both terms -- ZOUT, and gm.

Generally in individual transistors, the fundamental gm of the transistor element itself have a very high frequency response, but the parasitics around it (including base resistance, gate-drain capacitance) act to reduce the gm observed at the external terminals.

Comment: how to caculate the -3dB freq of gm?

Answer (score 1):

Gm is device deterministic and based on bias point. It doesn't have a frequency component. Now there are several other device parameters that do have frequency dependence, but gm isn't one of them.

To be precise,[image] so it's incredibly dependent on the bias point, which can change based on the magnitude of your input signal, not so much with frequency. Other parts such as Zout and parasitic capacitance determine the bandwidth.